# a \wedge variable in equation

Tags: equations

I want to write the equation attatched. I wrote it:

```
$X^\wedge f(t)$
```

but it didn't give me the required result. Can any one help?

[image: Sample required output]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

It's a `\hat` accent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $\hat{\mathbf{X}}^{\mathrm{f}}(t)$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

The math accent is `\hat` so:

```
$\hat{X}^f(t)$
```